# Does there exist an open neighborhood $U$ of $S$ and a smooth map $U\to S$ which is a retraction?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $S$ a smooth embedded submanifold of $M$. Does there exist an open neighborhood $U$ of $S$ and a smooth map $U\to S$ which is a retraction?

Answer (score 2):

Take a tubular neigborhood $U$ of $S$ (consult a book on differential topology; see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood). This contains $S$ as a strong deformation retract.